# Kivy_deps.glew.whl is not a supported wheel on this version

Tags: python, pip, kivy, fixed

I was trying to install kivy_deps.glew(version).whl with

> pip install absolute/path/to/file/kivy_deps.glew

And I get this error:

> kivy_deps.glew(version).whl is not a supported wheel on this version

I searched in the web and saw that some people said that the problem is because you shoud have python 2.7 and I have python 3.7. The version is of glew is cp27. So if this is the problem how to install python 2.7 and 3.7 in the same time and how to use both of them with pip.(i.e maybe you can use

> pip2.7 install

For python 2.7 and

> pip install

For python 3.7

P.S: My PC doesn't have an internet connection that's why i'm installing it with a wheel file. I have installed all dependecies except glew and sdl2. If there is any unofficial file for these two files for python 3.7 please link them.
I know this question has been asked before in stackoverflow but I didn't get any solution from it(it had only 1 anwser tho)
Update: I uninstalled python 3.7 and installed python 2.7, but pip and python weren't commands in cmd because python 2.7 hadn't pip. So I reinstalled python 3.7

Comment: I'm not sure if we have released binaries for Python 3.8 yet.

Comment: Which operating system? [Here are the official wheels](https://pypi.org/project/kivy-deps.glew/#files), but they are all for Windows. To select the correct pip for a specific python: `python2.7 -m pip install ...` or `python3.7 -m pip install ...` for example.

Comment: @sincoroc Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Just changed in the name of the file cp27 to cp37